# Sinch Push notification display name getting "null" in Android

Tags: android, sinch

```
private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
//setting display name to sinch client
sinchClient.setPushNotificationDisplayName(response.getFirst_name()+" "+response.getLast_name());
//Getting Dispaly name when push notification is shown.
NotificationResult result = sinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(intent);
        result.getDisplayName();
```

Comment: @Abhishek Patel do u have any idea on above issue.

Comment: what was the error display in logcat.?

Comment: @Abhishek Patel i declared sinch client a private SinchClient sinchClient = null; and getting result.getDisplayName() as "null" in my log

Comment: if you declare it as null therefore `sinchClient.setPushNotificationDisplayName(response.getFirst_name()+" "+response.getLast_name());` show my below answer

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is you should only define `private SinchClient sinchClient = null;` but you forgot to declare them like below

```
SinchClient sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(context)
                                               .applicationKey("<application-key>")
                                               .applicationSecret("<application-secret>")
                                               .environmentHost("sandbox.sinch.com")
                                               .userId("<user id>")
                                               .build();
```

Comment: i am using below code also but not working.                        sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();           is sender name is displaying in push notification for u?